# Cannot find error: calling items from libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, dictionary

I am having an issue with calling variables to add while within a definition which is in the class 'mountain'. It runs the error:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'picture'

Here is the code for it:

```
import random
class currencies:
    film = 5
class pictures:
    picture = {"m_goat": 0, "b_eagle": 0, "marmot": 0, "r_snake": 0, "m_lion": 0, "b_dragon": 0, "vulture": 0}
class location:
    city = True
    shop = False
    mountains = False
    desert = False
class mountain:
    #Travel to mountains
    def travel_m():
        print("You climb to the top of a tall mountain")
        location.mountains = True
        animals = ["mountain goat", "bald eagle", "marmot", "rattlesnake", "mountain lion"]
    animal_pics = ["m_goat", "b_eagle", "marmot", "r_snake", "m_lion"]
    if 1 == 1: #for simplicity I changed this to a non random number
        animal = random.randint(0, 4)
        str_animal = animals[animal]
        ans = input("You see a wild " + str_animal + ". Would you like to take a photo? (y/n) \n")
        if ans == "y" and currencies.film == 0:
            print("You cannot take a picture of this animal because you are out of film")
        elif ans == "y":
            currencies.film -= 1
            pictures.picture[animal_pics] = pictures.picture[animal_pics] + 1 #this is the line with the error
            print("You took a picture of the animal")
        elif ans == "n":
            print("The animal was left unbothered")
        else:
            print("I do not recognize that command")  
def pictures():
    print("You have " + str(pictures.pictures['m_goat']) + " picture(s) of mountain goats")
    print("You have " + str(pictures.pictures['b_eagle']) + " picture(s) of bald eagles")
    print("You have " + str(pictures.pictures['marmot']) + " picture(s) of marmots")
    print("You have " + str(pictures.pictures['r_snake']) + " picture(s) of rattlesnakes")
    print("You have " + str(pictures.pictures['m_lion']) + " picture(s) of mountain lions")
    mountain.travel_m()
```

Thank you for any help at all. I'm just learning the language but neither me nor my teacher could find an answer for it online. If it's something stupid, please do say

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You're missing an import, and your indentation kills the program in syntax check before we get to the error you half-cited.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
def pictures():
```

you're redefining the variable `pictures`. It now names the function, not the class that was defined earlier.

Give the function a name that doesn't conflict with the class, e.g.

```
def show_pictures():
```

Also, in the last function you use `pictures.pictures`. That should be `pictures.picture`.

After you fix those, this line is wrong:

```
pictures.picture[animal_pics] = pictures.picture[animal_pics] + 1
```

`animal_pics` is a list, you can't use it as a dictionary key. I think you meant:

```
pictures.picture[str_animal] += 1
```

Comment: Changed those things and got a new error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: In `pictures.picture[animal_pics]` , `animal_pics` is a list. I think you meant `str_animal`